# Calculating Macroblock Difference between macroblocks in JM reference software(H.264 Implementation)

Tags: c, implementation, h.264, video-encoding

I am studying H.264 AVC using JM reference software. I need to calculate the Macroblock difference between the Macroblock going to be encoded and the one which is collocated to it in the previous frame, in the naive implementation of H.264 i.e. JM older vesions. I read the code somewhat and went through the online documentation also, but all in vain. How can I get my task done?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly is your problem? Do you need help with some algorithm, or some code snippet? Or are you seeking conceptual clarity? If you can tell me which portion of code you are referring to, i will help you.

Comment: Actually I want to know what Mode a macroblock gets encoded against the macroblock difference(which is the Sum of absolute difference or Sum of squared error between macroblock being encoded and the one which is at the same location, as the current frame, in the previous frame).I think, JM doesn't records the macroblock difference, hence I need to modify the available JM reference source.Thus I want to ask how can I access the data in the Macroblocks(the pixel data of image) and what should be done to access the data in macroblocks in the previous frames, in JM reference software source.

Comment: Can you give me the link where i can download the code?

Comment: I think you should look at the area after/during the motion compensation is applied and before DCT is applied to each macroblock. This is definitely there because standard requires this.

Answer (score 0):

H.264/AVC **does not** calculate the residue of the current MB (in current frame) with the co-located one in previous frame. It is a more complicated process. As a brief example, consider the encoder wants to do an inter prediction estimation for current MB (which is called "P" frame). In this situation, firstly, the encoder finds the best motion vector (MV) for the current MB. In other words, the current MB is displaced in previous frame and the most similar one (which has the least value of SAD (Sum of Absolute Difference) with current MB) is chosen. Then the residue between these two MBs and the MV values are used to generate H.264 encoded bitstream. You can download and find complete tutorial [here](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/).
Also, you can find MB prediction function (at encoder side) and modify what you need here: lencod>src>[mc_prediction.c](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/doc/lenc/html/mc__prediction_8c_source.html)